# How to Integrate iAd or Admob banner like popUp (not full screen) but it display like popUp on center of screen in Application?

Tags: ios, admob, iad, ads

Hi i have seen some applications displaying advertisements in Application as a PopUp view Banner not in full-screen or not at Bottom or top as we did Generally. I do Google regarding this in [AdMob site](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals) or also read Apple doc [iAd_Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/BannerAdvertisements/BannerAdvertisements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH3-SW2) or [Working with Banner Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH4-SW12)

I would like to know about this type of displaying add and it's integration or SDK see the below screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use chartboost sdk for the ads in your games / app. This is available for all the platform (iOS / Android) Plugins also available for Unity. iOS integration documentation is available on [chartboost site](https://help.chartboost.com/documentation/ios). You can follow the steps and integrate it in your game easily.